# How to convert excel's numeric date value to Date suitable for storage in a db table using Talend

Tags: mysql, excel, date, csv, talend

I have an csv file with a number of columns some formatted as date,string, numeric.

I know Excel stores all its dates as numbers and the cell formatting thats applied is what makes it appear dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy-mm etc.

My problem is I have a column in the csv file which came from excel and I need to use talend to convert it from a numeric to a date value I can store in a database.

I haven't been able to find a component or function that will help me do this but before I try to solve it myself with code I wanted to see if others know a better way to accomplish it using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration?

Comment: I think you need to convert the column with the date in it to text/string before you save the sheet as a csv file ...

Comment: if it is csv then no need to open it using excel. open csv using notepad and see what is the actual date format and according to that convert it. please show us actual date format i would like to share solution, some of the format also mentioned on http://dwetl.com/2015/01/16/convert-string-to-date/ you can check there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

in the output csv file of date column in tmap.

Answer (score 2):

> Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day:   ddddd.tttttt
>   The integer portion of the number, ddddd, represents the number of days since 1900-Jan-0.  For example, the date 19-Jan-2000 is stored as 36,544, since 36,544 days have passed since 1900-Jan-0.  The number 1 represents 1900-Jan-1.
>   The fractional portion of the number, ttttt, represents the fractional portion of a 24 hour day.  For example, 6:00 AM is stored as 0.25, or 25% of a 24 hour day.  Similarly, 6PM is stored at 0.75,  or 75% percent of a 24 hour day.

So you can transform this number into date using a user code component like tJavaRow or by using a static routine, or it will be better (if possible) to make Excel print the field into the csv file in date format, to do that just select the cell or the column and change its number format in the home tab, it is set to 'standard' by default.

ref: [how excel stores dates](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to make the date a string

```
  =DAY(B2)&"/"&MONTH((B2))&"/"&YEAR((B2))
```

Comment: Thanks all for responding but the issue is I'm not processing the column using excel (so can't use formulas as suggested). Its Talend Data Integration I'm using and need to know the combination of components in that software application that will allow me to process a csv column which looks like a number but is in face MS Excel's internal way of storing date values so that if the number was 1234.56 it could be processed and it would correctly identified **by Talend** as 18/05/1903  13:26:24

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of others looking for an easy answer, this is what I do in these situations:

```
IF(LOCATE('/', Date_of_Birth) > 0 , STR_TO_DATE(Date_of_Birth, '%m/%d/%Y'), DATE_ADD('1900-01-01', INTERVAL b.Date_Of_Birth-2 DAY))
```

This example is from a source table that had different types of dates. Some were in a format like '01/01/2001' and some used the Excel format of number of days since 01/00/1900. I used an IF statement to handle them separately and the DATE_ADD portion refers to the Excel bit.